# How to start the graphql server in new version of next js 13.2 api route?

Tags: next.js, graphql, next-api, nextjs-app-beta

Unable to start the server in next js 13.2.

```
import { ApolloServer } from '@apollo/server';
import { startServerAndCreateNextHandler } from '@as-integrations/next';

const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    hello: () => 'world',
  },
};

const typeDefs = `#graphql
  type Query {
    hello: String
  }
`;

const server = new ApolloServer({
  resolvers,
  typeDefs,
});


export async function GET(request: Request) {
  return startServerAndCreateNextHandler(server);
}
```

I tried to integrate the graphql server in next js 13.2 app directory api route but it's not working for me.

Comment: why is it not working?

Comment: I am using next js 13.2 new api route handler with apollo server and next integration ( @as-integrations/next ). 

Expected behaviour is to start graphql server but it does not start the server.

http://localhost:3001/api/graphql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you have a different workflow requirement, you seem to be missing the default?

Replace `export async function ...` to

`export default startServerAndCreateNextHandler(server);`

Here's the reference for sample integration on NextJS
https://github.com/apollo-server-integrations/apollo-server-integration-next

Answer (score 0):

The `@as-integrations/next` package hasn't been updated to work with this feature yet, but in the [issues](https://github.com/apollo-server-integrations/apollo-server-integration-next/issues/79) someone has modified the code to work.